# How to get a stripe payment charge 'success' from a Cloud Function for Firebase?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project with angular 6, Stripe elements and Google's Firebase (with Cloud Functions). All are new to me!

For the life of me, I'm unable to figure out how I can return 'something' which states that the payment has been successful. Stripe API docs, state that it only returns an error call if there is an 'error'...

I can see that the card is being charged successfully from the charge object in Firebase.

What can I use to query this and return the 'status: paid' value to my front-end...so I can use an *ngIf to display confirmation/failure message?

I know i'm missing something dead simple here...! I really appreciate any help with this guys.

index.js (cloud function)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const stripe = require('stripe') 
(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

exports.stripeCharge = functions.database
.ref('/payments/{paymentId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
const payment = change.after.val();

const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

// checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
if (!payment || payment.charge) {
  return
}

return admin.database()
  .ref('/users/')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val()
  })

  .then(customer => {
    const amount = payment.amount;
    const idempotency_key = paymentId; // prevent duplicate charges
    const source = payment.token.id;
    const currency = 'gbp';
    const charge = { amount, currency, source };

    return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });
  })

  .then(charge => {
    admin.database()
      .ref(`/payments/${paymentId}/charge`)
      .set(charge)
      return true;
  })
});
```

Payment.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class PaymentService { 

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

// save the token to firebase, triggering the cloud function
processPayment(token: any, amount) {
  const payment = { token, amount }
  return this.db.list('/payments/').push(payment)
  }
}
```

payment.component.ts (here's my onSubmit handler for the checkout)

```
async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
//this.paymentProcess = true;
const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(this.card, {
  name: this.contactName,
  email: this.contactEmail
});

if (error) {  
  console.log('Something is wrong:', error);
} else {
  console.log('Success!', token);
    this.paymentSvc.processPayment(token, this.amount);
  }
  this.card.clear();
}
```

Comment: Just a small remark: you say that you are "working on a project with ... Google's **Firestore**" but note that your code is about the **Firebase Realtime Database**. There are two different database services offered by Firebase.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks ever so much Renaud. Thank you for flagging the 'Firestore' correction also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your Cloud Function code as follows, in order to return the promise returned by the asynchronous `.set(charge)` method.

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.database
.ref('/payments/{paymentId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
const payment = change.after.val();

const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

// checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
if (!payment || payment.charge) {
  return
}

return admin.database()
  .ref('/users/')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val()
  })

  .then(customer => {
    const amount = payment.amount;
    const idempotency_key = paymentId; // prevent duplicate charges
    const source = payment.token.id;
    const currency = 'gbp';
    const charge = { amount, currency, source };

    return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });
  })

  .then(charge => {
    return admin.database()  <-- Here return !!!!!!
      .ref(`/payments/${paymentId}/charge`)
      .set(charge);
      //return true;    <-- Here don't return !!!!!!
  })
});
```

---

In order to "return the 'status: paid' value to the front-end..", just set a [listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) to the `/payments/${paymentId}/charge` path and as soon as the charge has the correct status value, update your front-end.

---

Finally, note that with:

```
  ...
  .then(charge => {
    admin.database()
      .ref(`/payments/${paymentId}/charge`)
      .set(charge)
      return true;
  })
```

you were returning the value `true` to the Cloud Function platform, (indicating that the Function can be terminated) **before** the `set()` asynchronous operation was completed.